# Flexbox: justify-content: space-between?

Tags: css, flexbox

How do i make use of `justify-content: space-between;`? 
I need space between 2 articles in a section. And space between an img and a div in each article.

---

[How it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT4FX.png)
   and... 
[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmnpi.png)
.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Aetherr/pen/MPRJva

---

EDIT: changed `.flexcontainer` `flex-direction` to column

```css
/* === BELIEFS === */

.beliefs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* === RESERVATION === */

.reservation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* === FLEXCONTAINER === */

.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section.flexcontainer p {
  width: 500px;
}

section.flexcontainer img {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<section class="flexcontainer">
  <article class="beliefs">
    <img src="images/beliefs.jpg" alt="Our beliefs image" title="Our beliefs">
    <div>
      <h3>Our beliefs</h3>
      <p>When eating...</p>
      <p>We know...</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="reservation">
    <img src="images/reservation.jpg" alt="reservation image" title="Reservation">
    <div>
      <h3>Reservation</h3>
      <p>To fully...</p>
      <p>This way...</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Depends on which sizes are should be set.  If there is a size of a gap - then you should add it with margin and let blocks be flexible. If there are blocks with fixed `500px` widths then you should set fixed container width and height (try setting 1200px, then you'll see gaps between blocks).

Comment: Can't really work around the fixed widths. My assignment says: "The container is centered horizontally without
a specified width to the container. Both the images and the content have a width of 500px"

Comment: Then you can go with `padding/margin` as in the first answer, or just set fixed width to container, but for vertical gaps you'll also need paddings or fixed height (not really a good solution).

Comment: The problem with `padding/margin`: If i set e.g. 50px left, the second article has the 50px left too. Or i can specify this for both  `beliefs` and `reservation` but i think this is more of a 'work-around' solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`justify-content: space-between` will automatically fill the space between the elements on the flex-axis. This means that 1. you have no control over the amount of space between the elements, the browser will calculate and fill as it sees fit; 2. only the space on the flex-axis (default: row; x-axis) is filled so the space below your first row is not filled automatically.

The solution is to go back to good ol' margins. Do note that `margin` behaves slightly different on flex items, i.e. `margin: auto` will fill the available space with a margin.

```css
/* === RESERVATION === */
.reservation {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}


/* === FLEXCONTAINER === */

.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.flexcontainer p {
  width: 500px;
}

.flexcontainer article {
  display: flex;
}

.flexcontainer article img {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 24px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.flexcontainer article:nth-child(even) img {
  margin: 24px;      
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="flexcontainer">
  <article class="beliefs">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="Our beliefs image" title="Our beliefs">
    <div>
      <h3>Our beliefs</h3>
      <p>When eating...</p>
      <p>We know...</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="reservation">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="reservation image" title="Reservation">
    <div>
      <h3>Reservation</h3>
      <p>To fully...</p>
      <p>This way...</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation about `space-between`, i understand why margins are being used in this situation now.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add some padding.

```css
/* === BELIEFS === */
.beliefs {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

/* === RESERVATION === */
.reservation {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

/* ==== SLOGAN === */
.slogan {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin-bottom: 55px;
}

/* === FLEXCONTAINER === */
.flexcontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
section.flexcontainer p {
    width: 500px;
}
section.flexcontainer img {
    width: 500px;
    height:375px;
}
section.flexcontainer article:nth-child(even) img {
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
}
section.flexcontainer article:nth-child(odd) img {
    padding-right:25px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
}
```

```html
<section class="flexcontainer">
    <article class="beliefs">
        <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5926db217034dc5f91becd6b/master/w_1904,c_limit/so-logo-s.jpg" alt="Our beliefs image" title="Our beliefs">
        <div>
            <h3>Our beliefs</h3>
            <p>When eating is motivated by pleasure, rather than hunger. A bit of italian tradition in the middle of
                the
                modern
                world. A combination of traditional craftsmanship and the quality of “made in italy”.
            </p>
            <p>
                We know your time is money. The spaces are reduced in this modern world. To meet your desires, in
                every
                time and
                place, there we are that bring you a little moment of pleasure through spaces of your life.
            </p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="reservation">
        <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5926db217034dc5f91becd6b/master/w_1904,c_limit/so-logo-s.jpg" alt="reservation image" title="Reservation">
        <div>
            <h3>Reservation</h3>
            <p>
                To fully enjoy this experience you can call us on 646-755-8939 to book you table between 5.00
                pm-11.30
                pm
                (between
                11.30 am-11.30 pm on weekend).
            </p>
            <p>
                This way we can reserve you a special spot in our warm italian atmosphere. We advise to call upfront
                for
                any large
                group
            </p>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Edit: I changed the css so it's more dynamic if another article is added.

Comment: Yeah true, but it's kinda hard with this fixed width layout so I didn't bother :p

Comment: Fixed it! ;) @MrLister

Comment: This works fine for me! But isn't this more of a 'work-around' solution? I don't have much much experience with flexbox but i think this should be done with `justify-content: space-between;`

Comment: If i add another article, it needs those paddings too. And, justify-content feels like just the proper way to do this.

Comment: I edited the css so it's more dynamic so you can add another article ;)

Comment: Update: I need box shadows on the images, so i can't use paddings on those images or i get this result: http://prntscr.com/lbs175

Comment: Change the paddings to margins :)